# npm ERR! errno -4048

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

After 1 week break, I opened my pc again and when I want to 'expo start' from command window I get error like " 'expo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. " . And I tried to uninstall and install expo again and when I call " npm install --global expo-cli " I got this error.

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\Users\tuna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinUsbApi.dll
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\tuna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinUsbApi.dll'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\tuna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinUsbApi.dll'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\tuna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinUsbApi.dll'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\tuna\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\@expo\\.xdl.DELETE\\binaries\\windows\\adb\\AdbWinUsbApi.dll'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\tuna\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\@expo\\.xdl.DELETE\\binaries\\windows\\adb\\AdbWinUsbApi.dll',
npm ERR!   parent: 'expo-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tuna\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-03T15_36_23_690Z-debug.log
```

I couldnt find any solution that looks like my problem. Anybody has an idea to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ran this command inside VS Code? Try restarting VS Code and then running it.
close the metro bundler and use the install command again

Comment: Does the `C:\Users\tuna\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-03T15_36_23_690Z-debug.log` provide additional details?

Comment: I fixed this issue just now, but then I am getting error while opening expo from my mobile device. It says that " Uncaught Error: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.101:19000". What could be the problem?